# Log not working in yii2

Tags: yii2

i want to put a log in app.log ,My config file

```
 'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            'file' => [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                'logFile' => '@root/console/runtime/logs/app.log',
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

in controller action

```
 public function actionRankCalculation()
{
    $allConest = Contest::find()->where('isActive = 1')->all();
    Yii::trace('start calculating average revenue');
    $response = [];
    /** @var Contest $contest */
    foreach ($allConest as $contest) {
        $videoQuery = Video::find()->where('contest_id = ' . $contest->id);
        $videoQuery->andWhere('isActive = 1');
        $videoQuery->orderBy([
            'global_likes' => SORT_DESC,
            'id' => SORT_ASC,
        ]);
```

}
But  Yii::trace('start calculating average revenue'); not working

Comment: If your [path alias](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/) is correct then try `Yii::error('start calculating average revenue');` it will generate log file or add `
                `.

Comment: or add `'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'trace'],`

Answer (score -1):

You try this.Use **categories**. For example like below

```
            'targets' => [
           [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error'],
                 'categories' => ['test1'],
                'logFile' => '@app/Test/test1.log',


            ],
```

And use below one in controller action

```
 public function actionIndex(){    
   Yii::error('Test index action', $category = 'test1');   }
```