# Yii2 Yii::trace never found in logs despite config values

Tags: php, logging, yii2

I have the following config for logs:

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => getenv('YII_DEBUG') ? getenv('YII_TRACELEVEL') : 0,
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'except' => ['yii\db*'],
            'levels' => ['profile', 'trace', 'info', 'warning', 'error'],
            'logFile' => '@app/log/app.log',
            'logVars' => [],
            'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 20,
        ],
    ],
],
```

but when I call all the different level logs I can't seem to get traces to output to my app.log.

here's where we enter my code just as an example of how I'm calling the logs:

```
public function actionCreate() {
\Yii::trace("trace");
\Yii::info("info");
\Yii::warning("warning");
\Yii::error("error");
return;
```

and the output I find in app.log:

```
2016-10-24 19:15:58 [127.0.0.1][-][-][info][application] info
2016-10-24 19:15:58 [127.0.0.1][-][-][warning][application] warning
2016-10-24 19:15:58 [127.0.0.1][-][-][error][application] error
```

I've played around with adding/removing the levels from the level list, as well as outputting to codemix\streamlog\Targets php://stdout and php://stderr, and everything but trace level logs appear to work as you'd expect from the config. It looks like I'm doing it right according to the documentation found in the [Definitive Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html).

Maybe I'm missing something in my target? I saw someone had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871779/log-not-working-in-yii2) but they were simply missing the trace in their targets levels list and haven't responded on whether they solved their problem or not. I'd really appreciate any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `YII_DEBUG` defined in yourApp/web/index.php?

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```

Your code

```
'traceLevel' => getenv('YII_DEBUG') ? getenv('YII_TRACELEVEL') : 0,
```

is saying, that if `YII_DEBUG` is not defined, traceLevel would be 0. According to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-logger.html#$traceLevel-detail), traceLevel public property is defined like this:

> How much call stack information (file name and line number) should be
>   logged for each message. If it is greater than 0, at most that number
>   of call stacks will be logged. Note that only application call stacks
>   are counted.

Either set `YII_DEBUG` in yourApp/web/index.php, or change traceLevel property.

Comment: Based on [this code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/log/Logger.php#L138) `traceLevel` is not required for the message to be logged.

Comment: Bizley is correct, tracelevel just specifies how much of the callstack is reported along with the log. So if you set tracelevel to 3 it's going to look like

Comment: whoops, autosubmitted... it's going to look like:
`"log message"
in path/to/caller.php:1
in path/to/caller's_caller.php:2
in path/to/caller's_caller's_caller.php:3`